# Arch linux and dynamic disks?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, installation, arch-linux, dynamic-disk

Good day everyone

I have recently discovered that my hard drive is a dynamic disk (thanks to sh*tty Windows doing its thing). And, well, that essentially renders it impossible to install any linux distro.

I have found an article on the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Disks

It says that dynamic disk support can be enabled on arch by using a package called `ldmtool`. Now, if I use this tool and mount a dynamic partition, would it be possible to install and boot arch on it?

I am really frustrated at this point because I have nowhere to back up 1.7 TB of data and convert back to basic drive. And buying another hard drive is not really an option for me.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Try and see if your confident about what will be written, else see what other distros do?